# Have a different classpath for testing in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, spock

I have implemented a injection functionality into my framework so I can annotate implementations of my interface **BattleResolver** and then let the specific class I want these implementations to be injected, decide which one it takes depending on the annotation value of type enum.

```
@Resolver(Conflict.ConflictType.INFANTRY_CONFLICT)
public class TestArmorResolver implements BattleResolver {
}

@Resolver(ConflictType.ARMORED_CONFLICT)
public class TestInfantryResolver implements BattleResolver {
  // implementation
}
```

As you can see the difference between both classes is the conflict type they resolve. I have written a test which assures me that these classes are valid for injecting and that the proper class will be injected for a given conflict type.

Now I want to test the side-effects. Like having two classes resolve for the **same** type, which is not allowed for the framework.

The difference would simply look like this:

```
@Resolver(ConflictType.INFANTRY_CONFLICT)
public class TestInfantryResolverWrong implements BattleResolver {
  // implementation
}

@Resolver(Conflict.ConflictType.INFANTRY_CONFLICT)
public class TestArmorResolverWrong implements BattleResolver {
}
```

Both having the type *INFANTRY_CONFLICT*. I have no way to actually tell the test to take the second two and not the first two, so I can test for wrong user behaviour.

I would like to create a second classpath or a third to store my test fixture java classes. But how to actually direct the test to these classpaths to pickup the test fixtures. And how to let the test actually have access to the classes of the main classpath?

Comment: You'd need to share a bit more of your code, especially the one that does the resolving via Classloader. The easiest way would probably be to provide your own Classloader to your resolver for tests.

Comment: Have you considered using Spring and Profiles? It sounds like you are rebuilding that. If you are doing that intentionally you may want to look at how Spring profiles are implemented.

Comment: What about maven profiles? Wouldn't that work anyhow?#